# android.view.TextureView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView | Can't make it work

Tags: android, casting, textview, classcastexception, textureview

I'm building an app in Android Studio, in the app you can search in a SQLite database, it's not giving me any error when compiling but when it runs in the virtual device, it doesn't open, the app crash.

The Logcat says that there's an error in the cast, but I can find it:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.TextureView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Please note that I'm learning, so surely there's something I'm missing or wrong syntax

**Here's the code**:

```
class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView name,address,email,phone;

    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        address = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        email = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    }
}

public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<Friend> friends;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Friend> friends) {
        this.context = context;
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item,parent,false);
        return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.name.setText(friends.get(position).getName());
        holder.address.setText(friends.get(position).getAddress());
        holder.email.setText(friends.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.phone.setText(friends.get(position).getPhone());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return friends.size();
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Share your `layout_item` layout file with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `layout_item` xml. There you should have mistakenly defined `TextView` as `TextureView` at least one time.

Comment: Rene, thanks!! Yes! this was the error, I was like crazy checking the java code, the error was in the xml.